# jquery form validation. No plugin

Tags: jquery

What is the correct format to check for a value in a form field using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Focus on first form field.
    $("input:text:visible:first").focus();

    if ($('#movie_title') == "") {

        alert("No Film");
    }
});
```

Comment: $('#movie_title').val()

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) to get the value of the input field

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#movie_title').val() == "" ) {
        alert ("No Film");
    }

    // Focus on first form field.
    $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
});
```

Comment: Oh I see. I'm fairly new to Jquery just want to know what is the equivalent to these two Javascript functions. Document.getElementById()     innerHTML()  Hope thus makes some sense.